# How do I read these string diagrams?

Tags: category-theory

[In this post on bimonoid objects in monoidal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bimonoid), certain axioms are presented as "string diagrams", but nowhere can I find how I'm supposed to interpret them. I found somewhere that morphisms are visualized as circles, and objects as lines, which makes sense.

**However, I'm not sure how to actually translate them to equations, or which morphisms and objects are even involved.** Easiest for the answerer I think would just be to translate the diagrams to algebra, so I can generalize myself what the diagrams mean. (Or you could explain it, if this is easier to you).

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A red dot is the multiplication $\mu:B\otimes B\to B$ or unit $\eta:I\to B$ of $B$, while a blue dot is the comultiplication $\nu:B\to B\otimes B$ or counit $\varepsilon:B\to I$ of $B$. A crossing of wires is an application of the symmetry $\tau$ of the monoidal category. A blank space is the (identity morphism of) the unit object $I$ of the ambient category. Parallel wires indicate tensoring.

So for instance the first displayed diagram indicates that $\nu\circ \mu=\mu\otimes \mu\circ 1_B\otimes \tau_B\otimes 1_B\circ \nu\otimes \nu$. In set theoretic notation with $\otimes=\times$, this would be saying $(\nu(ab)_1,\nu(ab)_2)=(\nu(a)_1\nu(b)_1,\nu(a)_2\nu(b)_2)$, writing juxtaposition for $\mu$; in other words $\nu(ab)=\nu(a)\nu(b)$ in $B\otimes B$, so that $\nu$ is a monoid homomorphism as claimed.

You can get a more thorough background on string diagram calculus from Selinger's survey [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3347) and its references.

Comment: Great! thanks for the reference!

Comment: I would have said that the red dot is a comultiplication and the blue dot is multiplication :) I guess those are the remnants of studying Minkowski diagrams